# Finding a matrix representation of the linear transformation $T\colon P_2\to P_2$ ($T(f) = f''+2f'-f$)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

> Find a matrix representation of the linear transformation $T: P_2( \mathbb{R} ) \to P_2(\mathbb{R} )$, where $T$ is defined as $T(f(x)) = f''(x)+2f'(x) -f(x)$.

I know the standard ordered basis of $P_2( \mathbb{R} )$ is $\alpha = (1, x, x^2)$ but I am really shaky on how the basis changes as we define $T$. Does the standard ordered basis even change at all? How can we write this transformation's matrix representation? Do we just apply $T$ onto the standard ordered basis and see how it affects it?

**For example:**

We apply the transformation on each element of $\alpha$ to see how $T$ changes it.

- $T(1) = f''(1)+2f'(1) - f(x) = 0 + 0 - 1 = -1$.
- $T(x) = f''(x) + 2f'(x) - f(x) = 0 + 2 - f(x)$.
- $T(x^2) = f''(x^2) + 2f'(x^2) - f(x^2) = 2 + 4x - f(x^2)$.

Am I correct so far?

Now, putting this together can we say we have the matrix representation: 
$$[T]_\alpha = \begin{pmatrix} 1&2&2 \\ 0&1&4 \\ 0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: usually, the basis is fixed then we calculate the matrix of a transformation with respect to that basis. I think you should have $T(x)=2-x$ and $T(x^2)= 2+4x-x^2$. These have coordinate vectors $[2,-1,0]^T$ and $[2,4,-1]^T$ respective with respect to basis $\{ 1,x,x^2 \}$. You're missing some negative signs.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Thank you James! You're right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost correct, except for a few bugs.

First of all, I'm not sure why you leave "$f(x)$" in your expressions for $T(1)$, $T(x)$, and $T(x^2)$ (and the way the last expression is written is not correct). I would write them as:

$$T(1) = -1,$$
$$T(x) = 2-x,$$
$$T(x^2) = 2+4x-x^2.$$

As such, your matrix is almost correct, except for a few signs. I get:

\begin{pmatrix} -1&2&2 \\ 0&-1&4 \\ 0&0&-1 \end{pmatrix}

Comment: Does the sign matter? (Not sarcastic, I'm just curious since I thought you could just multiply the basis by a negative scalar to achieve the same effect)

Comment: NEVERMIND! GOT IT! Thank you!